# Инкремент переменной

Tags: переменные, javascript

Добрый день! У меня вот такая проблема: есть переменная, которую нужно инкрементировать, но когда я добавляю цикл в код, у меня перестает записываться он в мой `push()`. Вот мой код:

```
fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var file_i = 0;
        var d = new Date(file.lastModifiedDate);
        p.push('file_' + file_i + "=" + file.name +
                         ' date_'+ file_i + "=" + d.toISOString() +
                         ' size_' + file_i + "=" + file.size);
        file_i++;
        k--; //понижаем счетчик (данные записались)
        sendResults(); // вызываем функцию для обработки данных
    });
```

Как мне его переделать, чтобы переменная `file_i` инкрементировалась?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Она у вас локальная. Соответственно, инкрементироваться будет только пока жива функция, а функция дохнет после первого же инкремента.

Простейшее решение: сделать переменную внешней для функции.

```
fileEntry.file(function(file) {
    //file_i = 0; Spectre гений
    if(file_i===undefined){file_i=0;}
    var d = new Date(file.lastModifiedDate);
    p.push('file_' + file_i + "=" + file.name +
                     ' date_'+ file_i + "=" + d.toISOString() +
                     ' size_' + file_i + "=" + file.size);
    file_i++;
    k--; //понижаем счетчик (данные записались)
    sendResults(); // вызываем функцию для обработки данных
});
```

Более сложное(что, по сути, тоже делает переменную внешней, но уже не глобальной):

```
function incrementfile(file,file_i){
var d = new Date(file.lastModifiedDate);
        p.push('file_' + file_i + "=" + file.name +
                         ' date_'+ file_i + "=" + d.toISOString() +
                         ' size_' + file_i + "=" + file.size);
if(file_i<100500){
incrementfile(file,++file_i);
}
}
```

Comment: Не помогло, так же не инкрементируется. Ни первый ни второй варианты.

Comment: @dajver, покажите контекст.

Comment: Как его взять? Что за контекст?

Comment: естественно не икрементурует, т.к. в начале выполнения функции происходит:

    file_i = 0;

Comment: SPectre, ты гений. +100500. *убил себя об стену*

Comment: > `if(file_i===undefined){file_i=0;}`

Зачем? Можно же проще:

    var file_i = 0;
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        // ...

Comment: Панически боюсь такого. =) Я ненормальный?

Comment: а если не переопределить то будет равно undefined

Answer (score 1):

А ведь достаточно было вынести переменную за функцию:

```
var p;

function o() {
//...
p++;
}
```

И все инкрементируется.